# Enabling iCloud Storage API for Application ID

Tags: ios, icloud

I know that after enabling iCloud I need to regenerate Provisioning profile. My question is: is it going to break my existing application since new version will not be released until Apple approves it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ika it would not break your app. Apple treats every upgrade as a new version. it would not break your application.